# Google cloud spark context fails to initialize

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Submitting a job in Spark in Google Cloud suddenly fails with this message:

`ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1461774669718_0005. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 194 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 194.
The number of live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.`

The cluster I am using was working properly, until recently and no changes have been made in the code that sets the SparkContext. It seems tat safe mode is not switched off for a reason. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: If you SSH into the master node and type `hdfs dfsadmin -report` it should provide a report of the datanodes; in your case it sounds like something may have caused the datanodes to go unhealthy. If you have project ids or cluster names you don't want to share publicly, you can email dataproc-feedback@google.com to reach the Google team (though  support/troubleshooting there is best-effort; official support requests needing response guarantees would need to go through [official support channels](https://cloud.google.com/support/) )

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm having the same issue. I've tried recreating the cluster several times with different configs, but all I get is this:(

Comment: I restarted all the cloud machines and gave it 5 min. It seems that it got stuck in the initialization phase.

Comment: Ah, yeah I just solved mine too. Turns out I had messed up my firewall...